# SSH tunnel and reverse SSH tunnel at the same time on the same port

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, netcat

I have a computer A, a server B (Azure VM) and a second computer C. I want to connect from A to C through the server B.

Setup:

```
A: ssh -i location_of_private_key -L 12000:public_IP_of_B:20000 user@serverB

C: ssh -i location_of_private_key -R 20000:localhost:12000 user@serverB
```

Testing:

```
A: nc localhost 12000

C: nc -l 12000
```

But the first testing command (in A) fails, I can't establish connection to B on port 20000.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Is there any service on public_IP_of_B on port 20000 listening? If yes - is it reachable from serverB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a couple of mistakes:

- Port forwardings by default listen only on `localhost` so that's what you have to connect to in the first command.
- You need to start the listener before you try to connect to it.

Fix those two mistakes and it should work.

Comment: Whoo, I was 10000% sure I had also tried to start the listener first (this is quite logical ^^). But maybe I had another mistake somewhere else. Anyway, thanks a lot, this fixed my problem ! :)